# How to autoincrement nuget package version on git merge

Tags: git, nuget

I have nuget package and right now I am versioning it manually in .csproj file.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
     <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
     <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
     <Version>1.1.0</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I want to achieve automatic increment when merge request is merged to master. I do not need it to be saved in version in .csproj (although it will be nice to have) but main goal is to have generated new nuget with higher version.

Current pipeline is doing only simple upload. It is working all right but only with predefined version.

```
script:
   - echo "Creating nuget"
   - dotnet restore
   - dotnet build -c release
   - dotnet pack -c release -o publish
   - dotnet nuget add source "${SOURCE}" --name gitlab --username "${TOKEN_NAME}" --password "${TOKEN_PASSWORD}" --store-password-in-clear-text
   - dotnet nuget push "publish/*.nupkg" --source gitlab
```

Any ideas will be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [GitVersion](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GitVersion.Tool). It will semantically version your package based on tags, releases, commits, etc.

Theoretically, it's as easy as

```
echo "Creating nuget"
dotnet restore
dotnet tool install --global GitVersion.Tool --version 5.*
dotnet-gitversion
dotnet build -c release
dotnet pack -c release -o publish
etc...
```

but you should probably [read the documentation](https://gitversion.net/docs/usage/cli/installation) before copy pasting any code.